# file_get_contents не работает и curl тоже

Tags: php

У меня не работает на хостинге file_get_contents и curl[image: Скрин]

У меня allow_url_fopen включен
file_get_contents и curl получает пустоту(получает "")

Comment: Посмотрите лог ошибок.

Comment: Вобще ннет ошибока. Просто получает пустоту.

Comment: Значит это правильный ответ от сервера